# RaspberryPi MOSI/MISO on java with PI4J

Tags: java, pi4j

Sorry for my English, but I will try :)

I need help with working with RFID reader RC522 (like [this](http://www.electrodragon.com/product/mifare-rc522-rfid-card-readerdetector-ic-card/)). I connected it to Pi with help of [this manual](http://fuenteabierta.teubi.co/2013/07/utilizando-el-lector-nfc-rc522-en-la.html), but I cant write right code on `Java` and `Pi4J`, which will read data from cards with help of rc522, and use MOSI/MISO pins. Other manuals use serial port for get data, but I need use MISO.

Is it real?
I cant understand which type of "RaspiPin" I should use for MOSI/MISO pins? 
Have anybody projects on github, which work with MOSI/MISO (12/13 gpio pins) and `Pi4J`?

Answer (score 0):

As you might know ,you will need pin 19 21 23  which are mosi miso sclk respectively .This is the SPI port on raspi.Have a look in these links.

- http://pi4j.com/apidocs/com/pi4j/wiringpi/Spi.html
- http://www.savagehomeautomation.com/projects/raspberry-pi-programming-pi-face-with-java-pi4j.html

and  last but not least google>  spi pi4j

also adding a PiFace which is compatible with pi4j and has a full api ready for you.

Comment: This reply assumes that the OP is using an old RPI. The new RPI B+ has different pin outs -> http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/simple-guide-to-the-rpi-gpio-header-and-pins/

Comment: Also, I think that spi must be activated in raspi-config.